# Ansible - How to resolve - Permission denied - when using lineinfile module

Tags: ansible, directory, permission-denied

**Backgruond**

We have kafka installation with 3 brokers where I need to add *ssl.enabled.protocols = TLSv1.2* to server.properties file on  each broker.

I login to the broker servers with service account and  then do `sudo su` to login as root.  Once I do that,  I have permissions to manually edit the server.properties file.

I do not have password for root.

I am  asked to edit these files frequently, so I am trying to do an ansible script for it using the lineinfile module.

I am running this script from the svcacct,  after logging-in to the svcacct on one of the broker servers.

**Current Script**

```
---

- name: Modify server.properties
  hosts: kafka_broker
#  become: true
  become: yes
#  become_user: root
#  become_method: su
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_extra_args: "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
    ansible_host_key_checking: false

  tasks:

    - name: "Add the line if it does not exist"
      become: yes
      #become_user: root
      tags: addifnotexists
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/kafka/server.properties
        line: "ssl.enabled.protocols = TLSv1.2"
        insertafter: EOF
        state: present
        backup: yes
      register: addifnotexists
    - debug: var=addifnotexists
```

I added these lines below after them being provided and accepted as solutions to some other similar types of questions, but hasn't helped in this case

```
become_user: root
become_method: su
```

**Current output / error**

```
TASK [Add the line if it does not exist] ********************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [server031]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to server031 closed.
", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"/export/home/svcacct/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1625914934.16-210880192166305/AnsiballZ_lineinfile.py\", line 114, in <module>
    _ansiballz_main()
  File \"/export/home/svcacct/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1625914934.16-210880192166305/AnsiballZ_lineinfile.py\", line 106, in _ansiballz_main
    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
  File \"/export/home/svcacct/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1625914934.16-210880192166305/AnsiballZ_lineinfile.py\", line 49, in invoke_module
    imp.load_module('__main__', mod, module, MOD_DESC)
  File \"/tmp/ansible_lineinfile_payload_B0u2v9/__main__.py\", line 538, in <module>
  File \"/tmp/ansible_lineinfile_payload_B0u2v9/__main__.py\", line 529, in main
  File \"/tmp/ansible_lineinfile_payload_B0u2v9/__main__.py\", line 271, in present
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/kafka/server.properties'
", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE
See stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

fatal: [server016]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to server016 closed.
", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"/export/home/svcacct/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1625914934.03-17499089691682/AnsiballZ_lineinfile.py\", line 114, in <module>
    _ansiballz_main()
  File \"/export/home/svcacct/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1625914934.03-17499089691682/AnsiballZ_lineinfile.py\", line 106, in _ansiballz_main
    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
  File \"/export/home/svcacct/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1625914934.03-17499089691682/AnsiballZ_lineinfile.py\", line 49, in invoke_module
    imp.load_module('__main__', mod, module, MOD_DESC)
  File \"/tmp/ansible_lineinfile_payload_JtsINR/__main__.py\", line 538, in <module>
  File \"/tmp/ansible_lineinfile_payload_JtsINR/__main__.py\", line 529, in main
  File \"/tmp/ansible_lineinfile_payload_JtsINR/__main__.py\", line 271, in present
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/kafka/server.properties'
", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE
See stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

fatal: [server033]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to server033 closed.
", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"/export/home/svcacct/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1625914934.08-221449168676184/AnsiballZ_lineinfile.py\", line 114, in <module>
    _ansiballz_main()
  File \"/export/home/svcacct/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1625914934.08-221449168676184/AnsiballZ_lineinfile.py\", line 106, in _ansiballz_main
    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
  File \"/export/home/svcacct/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1625914934.08-221449168676184/AnsiballZ_lineinfile.py\", line 49, in invoke_module
    imp.load_module('__main__', mod, module, MOD_DESC)
  File \"/tmp/ansible_lineinfile_payload_GoJyG7/__main__.py\", line 538, in <module>
  File \"/tmp/ansible_lineinfile_payload_GoJyG7/__main__.py\", line 529, in main
  File \"/tmp/ansible_lineinfile_payload_GoJyG7/__main__.py\", line 271, in present
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/kafka/server.properties'
", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE
See stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

**ansible --version**

```
ansible 2.8.4
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/export/home/svcacct/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Aug 13 2020, 02:51:10) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
```

From what I was reading, `become: yes` sets the user to root, but it doesn't appear to be so.  What am I missing?

Is there something else I need to look at or check?  How can I resolve the permissions issue from within the script?

Please let me know, if any information / details are  missing from the question as well.

Thank you

**Update**

Tried verifying what the user shows up as, since adding the `become: yes` at either play or task level still generated the same permissions error.

---

```
- name: Modify server.properties
  hosts: kafka_broker
  become: true
 #Tried the identity with "become: true" here

  vars:
    ansible_ssh_extra_args: "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
    ansible_host_key_checking: false

  tasks:

    - name: I am confused
     #Tried the identity with "become: true" here 
      become: true
      command: 'whoami'
      register: myidentity

    - name: my secret identity
      debug:
        msg: "{{ myidentity.stdout }}"

    - name: "Add the line if it does not exist"
      become: true
      tags: addifnotexists
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/kafka/server.properties
        line: "ssl.enabled.protocols = TLSv1.2"
        insertafter: EOF
        state: present
        backup: yes
      register: addifnotexists
    - debug: var=addifnotexists
```

Both the times I expected the user to show as `root`, but both the times it showed up as `svcacct`

```
TASK [my secret identity] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server016] => {
    "msg": "svcacct"
}
ok: [server031] => {
    "msg": "svcacct"
}
ok: [server033] => {
    "msg": "svcacct"
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that in real life you are chaining privilege escalation metthod (i.e. `sudo su`) while [ansible does not support that](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#only-one-method-may-be-enabled-per-host). I suggest your read the rest of the linked page to understand privilege escalation.

Comment: if you are talking about these 2 lines -   _become_user: root_  **and**  _become_method: su_,  I added them later because I was getting the mentioned error without them too and saw some posts where that was the solution.  I just tried commenting those 2 lines, resulting in  the same error

Comment: No, I'm talking about how you do today: `I login to the broker servers with service account and then do 'sudo su' to login as root`. This most surely means that your user has the right to use `sudo` only to issue the `su` command to then become root. This is not supported by ansible. You either use `sudo` or `su` (or any other supported escalation method) but you should then be able to issue any command. Read the rest of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try to understand it.  I do  not know the difference between the two, but I do sudo su, so that I don't have to prepend each command with sudo.  Otherwise, I am also able to do sudo cat or sudo vi and  other commands by prepending sudo to the command when being logged-in using the service account.  So, the account has permission to perform other actions, right?  Could you please let me know,  how I should indicate to use sudo in the script?

Comment: Quick tip: try to issue manually on your target server `sudo -i`. If this drops you inside a root shell, that means you can use ansible with `become: true` and `become_method: sudo`. The later being the default, you can omit it if you wish. And side note regarding your commented lines: in ansible/yaml, for boolean values, `true`, `yes`, `on`,`1`, are all equivalent.

Comment: This is the output - **sudo -i

Welcome root. This is a qa server. BU is  lann**  So, I can use ansible for using root privileges, right?  Should this - `become: true and become_method: sudo` - be added at top level or task level?  Or if I have only one task, would it make a difference either way?   Thanks

Comment: As reported earlier, you just need `become: true` and actually nothing else (because `become_user: root` and `become_method: sudo` are the defaults as reported in the above linked documentation you should read now). In your opinion, what is the difference between putting this directive at play level vs task level? <= If you cannot answer this question, I suggest your practice, test, and read a bit more [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/index.html). Use the one that suits your needs depending on your current context and requirement.

Comment: @Zeitounator - Sorry to keep asking this question.  But from the documentation I understood, if we define `become: true` at play level, it is applicable to all tasks unless overridden and if defined at task level, then of course applicable to that task.   The reason I am still confused is that I tried it both ways, but I still get the same error about permission.  And to check I also added another task with `whoami` and that displays `svcacct` in both cases.   I  have added the updated script to the question.  So, I am wondering, if there is something else missing in the script or set-up.

Comment: So far, I don't see a mention of the username with which you run the ansible playbook. Is it the same as the one with that can run `sudo cat`, `sudo vi`, etc.?

Comment: Yes, I am logging in with 'svcacct' id and run the playbook from that account.  When logged in to that account, I can successfully do sudo cat / sudo vi etc.